# Add print button to SharePoint modern experience list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I want to add a print button to SharePoint modern experience list views in both Lists and Libraries.

In classic view print dialog can be opened with executing a javascript function in `CommandAction` property.

```
CommandAction="javascript:print();"
```

Is there any way to achieve similar functionality modern experience?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this type of customization is disabled in the Modern list and libraries experience by Microsoft.

So, only option right now is to keep using classic lists experience if you want the functionality or wait for MS to allow customization.

Uservoice link - [Allow Javascript customization and CSS branding/theming in the new Document Library Experience](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th) - upvote on this link and make your voice heard.

MSDN link - [Customize modern list and libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries)